# Why does my SQL statement return 1 even though both tables are empty?

Tags: php, sql

I have two tables items and bids. I want to join them and select the highest bid for each item. As of right now the table is empty and I want to make it so that when I do a mysqli_num_rows it should return 0 but it returns 1. When it returns 0 I want to display text that says there are no new items

```
SELECT i_name, i_id, MAX(price) FROM items JOIN bid USING (i_id)
```

My questions are:

Why does it return 1?
How do I fix my statement?

Comment: When you have an aggregate function without GROUP BY it always returns one row. mysqli_num_rows would be pointless for this query...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, it returns one row because you are including MAX(price), so the query will always return its value. In case the table is empty, it will return null, so that's one row.

Every time you include an aggregate function and don't include a `GROUP BY` clause, the result is one row.

The fix is simple: use the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT i_name, i_id, MAX(price) FROM items JOIN bid USING (i_id) GROUP BY i_name, i_id
```

That query returns 0 rows when there are no items and when the existing items have no bids.

However, if you want the query to also show items with no bids and only return 0 rows if there are no items, use a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT i_name, i_id, MAX(price) FROM items LEFT JOIN bid USING (i_id) GROUP BY i_name, i_id
```

Comment: alright it worked when i have no items but now that i have an item it doesn't work.

Comment: Please post your tables and post your output, because IMHO it should work. Is that item correctly included in both tables?

Comment: it is not included in both tables as no bids have been placed so maybe i need to adjust it to some degree. Basically what i want to be able to do is add the items to an items table. then display the items and allow users to view and place bids on the items. maybe when i create the items i should place a starting bid of 0 in order to get the item in both tables?

Comment: Your query is JOINING on i_id columns, so the item should be in both tables. The query I gave returns 0 rows even if there is an  item with no bids. The question is: what do you want it to do?

Comment: Basically what i want to be able to do is add the items to an items table. then display the items and allow users to view and place bids on the items. maybe when i create the items i should place a starting bid of 0 in order to get the item in both tables?

Comment: can you show me? im trying to understand but i still haven't fully grasped sql stuff. not enough experience

Comment: I updated my answer. Didn't test it, but I think it should work.